# How to determine which python is used by mac and mac programs

Tags: python, macos, path, textmate

I've read through several questions and pages on the how and why of this, but after taking a look on my mac yesterday I found that I currently have 6 versions of python on my machine.

Three are located in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions (2.5, 3.1, 3.2), and then I have three more in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions (2.5, 2.6, and another).

Terminal seems to use MacPython 2.5 from the first path. I found that it is recommended that I let my Mac itself use MacPython and that I don't try to change that. I managed to add a 3.2 reference from the first path to $PATH, but Terminal doesn't really seem to pick up on that.

For Python development I have used IDLE in the past, but it doesn't have any syntax highlighting, and so I moved over to TextMate.

I have several questions:
- Why are there so many versions and are they all being used?
- How can I get all programs to use the same version?
- Why do some versions have IDLE and some don't, and more importantly why do the ones that don't, have all the 'Extras' installed, like PyOBjC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **How to know which Python is the used:**

   In the Terminal, type `which python`. It will show you the path to the active Python.
2. **Why so many versions:**

   Probably leftovers of previous system upgrades: Tiger -> Leopard -> Snow Leopard, maybe.
3. **How to point everything to the Python you want:**

   In your `.profile` or `.bashrc` add the line:

   ```
    alias python='/path/to/the/python/of/your/choice'
   ```

I'd recommend to install Python via MacPorts. It's well maintained and comes with a CLI "chooser" allowing you to, well… choose the active Python.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I managed to get things to work as I want them.